# Chart is not defined in a Rails 6 view page with webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I'm trying to figure out the right way to use a `Chart` from `chart.js` in a Rails 6 app using webpacker. I would like my chart generation javascript code to remain in the page since I'll be dynamically generating it from the view.

I started with

```
yum add chartjs
```

then added to the application pack (and `javascript_pack_tag` is in my `application.html.erb`)

```js
// app/javascript/packs/application.js
import Chart from "chartjs";
```

And then, in a view I try and use that library:

```rb
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <canvas id="backlog-chart" width="100%" height="400px">
      <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById('backlog-chart').getContext('2d');
        new Chart(ctx, { ...
```

This fails with an `Chart is not defined` javascript error.

Things I've tried:

1. the `require("chartjs")` form of including the library in `application.js` seems to have no impact one way or the other.
2. I tried adding to `config/webpack/environment.js` to the `ProvidePlugin` object with `Chart: "chartjs/chart.js"` but no changes.
3. And I've tried adding `import Chart from "chart.js"` directly to the `<script>` section in the view but this fails with a "import only allowed in module" error on the browser.

My javascript skills have definitely not kept up with the last couple years of new technologies so any suggestions on the right way to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `Chart` in a script in your HTML body because `Chart` hasn't been globably defined. You could import the chart.js javascript by embedding the script tag, and then `Chart` would be available. But you said you wanted to use Webpacker, so...

Include your chart definition in your `application.js`, rather than in the script tag.

```js
// app/javascript/packs/application.js
import Chart from "chartjs";

var ctx = document.getElementById('backlog-chart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {...});
```

This will target that canvas in your HTML:

```html
<canvas id="backlog-chart" ... />
```

Comment: By the way, I usually place bits of javascript in a folder called `modules` under my javascript directory, and then require everything in that folder in application.js. This keeps the application.js file nice and clean. 
`requireAll(require.context("./modules/", true, /\.js$/));`

Comment: Thank you. I think you've helped me define what my question actually is: can I globally define `Chart` using webpacker. I don't want to put the chart code in `application.js` because I want to dynamically generate the chart using data from the controller in that view. (p.s. also I don't "want" to use Webpacker.... just forced to with Rails 6 if I want to be omakase :-)

Comment: @GSP I have a similar need like you mentioned in your comment above. In other words I want to call a function imported in `app/javascript/packs/application.js` and then use that function in view. Can you please help me by letting me know how you solved it? Thanks.

Comment: The short answer, is that I put the dynamic data on the page but put the javascript in the pack and then use the javascript to select the data from the page and pass it to Chart for rendering.

Comment: @JigneshGohel @GSP `global.Chart = require('chart.js')`